# How to work with PHP, HTML, CSS & JS in same file simultaneously using eclipse for php

Tags: php, eclipse, html, text-editor, code-hinting

Please tell me how to work with **PHP, HTML, CSS & JS** within same file **simultaneously**. I mean I do this most often, that the file is `*.php` extension but I have to write HTML, CSS, PHP, JS all in the same file.

So that for each language **code hinting could work, it doesn't work**.

I have already download

> - Eclipse for PHP
> - Eclipse for JavaScript & Web

but both run separately. How can I combine? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the menu:

```
Help -> Install New Software
```

Make sure you have the package for `Web Developer Tools`

Then Eclipse should provide the desired highlighting.

Comment: can you please tell the exact name of the package? because this "web developer tools" i cannot find in the marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Help -> install New Software

Select the following three options under “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development”:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse Web Developer Tools

Follow the prompts from there.